# Correlative by group with special criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We need to get the result of the column NEED, need the correlative grouped by the GROUP column in the order of the ORDER column and that increases when the FLAG column changes.

```
GROUP   ORDER   FLAG    NEED
1111    1       0       1
1111    2       0       1
1111    3       1       2
1111    4       1       2
1111    5       1       2
1111    6       1       2
1111    7       1       2
1111    8       0       3
1111    9       1       4
1111    10      1       4
1111    11      0       5
1111    12      0       5
1111    13      0       5
6666    1       0       1
6666    2       0       1
6666    3       1       2
6666    4       1       2
```

We try the following code, but we need something cleaner with support for SQL Server 2008

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp2','u') is not NULL
drop table #temp2
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(oRDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
INTO #temp2
FROM DBO.PRUEBA​

SELECT T1.*
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN T1.NUM_GROUP = T2.NUM_GROUP and t1.NUM_FLAG = t2.NUM_FLAG THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.NUM_GROUP ORDER BY T1.rn)[Rank]
FROM #temp2 T1
LEFT JOIN #temp2 T2 ON T1.rn = T2.rn+1
order by t1.NUM_GROUP, t1.NUM_ORDER
```

I share the creation of tables and records

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.PRUEBA
(
    NUM_GROUP INT,
    NUM_ORDER INT,
    NUM_FLAG INT
)

INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 2, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 4, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 5, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 6, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 7, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 8, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 9, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 10, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 11, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 12, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (1111, 13, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (6666, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (6666, 2, 0)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (6666, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA VALUES (6666, 4, 1)

SELECT * FROM DBO.PRUEBA
```

Comment: What do you mean by *cleaner*? Does the query give you the results you want or not?

Comment: The query code does not work in sql server 2008, the code shown does not look very clean.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? And what do you mean by clean? It *looks* perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

A possible optimalization is to first create the temporary table.

Instead of using a `SELECT INTO`.

And with a primary key that benefits the self-join that's used to get the previous NUM_FLAG.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DBO.PRUEBA
> (
>     NUM_GROUP INT NOT NULL,
>     NUM_ORDER INT NOT NULL,
>     NUM_FLAG INT NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (NUM_GROUP, NUM_ORDER)
> );
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO DBO.PRUEBA 
> (NUM_GROUP, NUM_ORDER, NUM_FLAG)
> VALUES
>   (1111, 1, 0)
>  ,(1111, 2, 0)
>  ,(1111, 3, 1)
>  ,(1111, 4, 1)
>  ,(1111, 5, 1)
>  ,(1111, 6, 1)
>  ,(1111, 7, 1)
>  ,(1111, 8, 0)
>  ,(1111, 9, 1)
>  ,(1111, 10, 1)
>  ,(1111, 11, 0)
>  ,(1111, 12, 0)
>  ,(1111, 13, 0)
>  ,(6666, 1, 0)
>  ,(6666, 2, 0)
>  ,(6666, 3, 1)
>  ,(6666, 4, 1)
> ```

> ```
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpPRUEBA', 'U') IS NOT NULL
>     DROP TABLE #tmpPRUEBA; 
>
> CREATE TABLE #tmpPRUEBA
> (
>     NUM_GROUP INT NOT NULL,
>     RN_GROUP INT NOT NULL,
>     NUM_ORDER INT NOT NULL,
>     NUM_FLAG INT NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (NUM_GROUP, RN_GROUP)
> );
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO #tmpPRUEBA
> (NUM_GROUP, NUM_ORDER, NUM_FLAG, RN_GROUP)
> SELECT NUM_GROUP, NUM_ORDER, NUM_FLAG
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>       PARTITION BY NUM_GROUP 
>       ORDER BY NUM_ORDER) AS RN_GROUP
> FROM DBO.PRUEBA;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> t1.NUM_GROUP, 
> t1.NUM_ORDER, 
> t1.NUM_FLAG,
> SUM(CASE 
>     WHEN t1.NUM_FLAG = t2.NUM_FLAG 
>     THEN 0 
>     ELSE 1 
>     END)
>     OVER (PARTITION BY t1.NUM_GROUP 
>           ORDER BY t1.RN_GROUP) AS [Rank]
> FROM #tmpPRUEBA t1
> LEFT JOIN #tmpPRUEBA t2
>   ON t2.NUM_GROUP = t1.NUM_GROUP
>  AND t2.RN_GROUP = t1.RN_GROUP - 1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> NUM_GROUP | NUM_ORDER | NUM_FLAG | Rank
> --------: | --------: | -------: | ---:
>      1111 |         1 |        0 |    1
>      1111 |         2 |        0 |    1
>      1111 |         3 |        1 |    2
>      1111 |         4 |        1 |    2
>      1111 |         5 |        1 |    2
>      1111 |         6 |        1 |    2
>      1111 |         7 |        1 |    2
>      1111 |         8 |        0 |    3
>      1111 |         9 |        1 |    4
>      1111 |        10 |        1 |    4
>      1111 |        11 |        0 |    5
>      1111 |        12 |        0 |    5
>      1111 |        13 |        0 |    5
>      6666 |         1 |        0 |    1
>      6666 |         2 |        0 |    1
>      6666 |         3 |        1 |    2
>      6666 |         4 |        1 |    2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4b3ea013bedcdbbd84eb514e103b6721)*